# error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task

Tags: c#, teamcity

Please note that I am able to build this project in Visual Studio Professional 2017:  https://github.com/briannoyes/WPFMVVM-StarterCode

But when I try to run the build in Team City 2019.1 it gave me this error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2924,5): error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x86".
```

Then I found this link:

['dotnet build' error after migrating dotnetcore project to 1.0.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909874/dotnet-build-error-after-migrating-dotnetcore-project-to-1-0-4)

From there I added this to the project as suggested in a comment:

```
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
```

But now I am getting this error:

> Problem reported from build script (1) 
>   Customers\AddEditCustomerView.xaml.cs(25,13): error CS0103: The name
>   'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
>   Customers\CustomerListView.xaml.cs(25,13): error CS0103: The name
>   'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
>   OrderPrep\OrderPrepView.xaml.cs(25,13): error CS0103: The name
>   'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
>   Orders\OrderView.xaml.cs(25,13): error CS0103: The name
>   'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
>   MainWindow.xaml.cs(25,13): error CS0103: The name
>   'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context CSC :
>   error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable
>   for an entry point···   Build failure condition (1)  Process exited
>   with code 1

Here are the settings I have in my build step:

[image]

Here is the full build log:

https://pastebin.com/1JdhKWPf

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. You've posted a shot of your step 2 setup, but based on the log it's step 4 that's failing. You say you're able to build the project in Visual Studio, but can you build it on your own machine from the command line?

Comment: I can build on the command line and it gives me no errors using this command:  msbuild ZzaDesktop.sln

Comment: @Nanhydrin, thanks for the tip.  I disabled build step 4 and it now works.  Please post as answer and I will mark is as the solution.

Comment: I don't feel like I've earned that one, I just steered you in the right direction :) You should answer it yourself and accept your answer so you can say why it was the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the latest TeamCity by default supports .NET Core, so it automatically added this step:

[image]

But the only build step I really needed was step 2 given in my question for my WPF application using the .NET Framework 4.7, **NOT** .NET Core, so I disabled step 4 and the build now works.